# Pass a string as variable name in dplyr::coalesce

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

I'm trying to create a new column with the first NA value from a set of columns using a variable for the column names in `dplyr::coalesce()`. How to make it work?

I have tried using coalesce() with the actual column names and it works. It fails when I pass it a variable.

```r
tb <- tibble(a = c("a", NA, "a", NA, "a"), 
            b = c(NA, "b", NA, NA, NA), 
            c = c('c', 'c', 'c', 'c', NA))

df <- tb %>%
  mutate(combined = coalesce(a, b, c))
```

This works with the following output

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  a     b     c     combined
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
1 a     NA    c     a       
2 NA    b     c     b       
3 a     NA    c     a       
4 NA    NA    c     c       
5 a     NA    NA    a
```

However, when I create a variable for the column names:

```r
uCols <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

and run similar code:

```r
df <- tb %>%
  mutate(combined = coalesce(uCols))
```

I get the following error:

```r
Error: Column `combined` must be length 5 (the number of rows) or one, not 3
```

I have tried using `enexprs(uCols)` but that does not work.

How do I pass the `uCols` variable to `coalesce()` so that it works as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to convert the strings to symbols (`syms` from `rlang`) and then evaluate (`!!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
tb %>%
   mutate(combined = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(uCols)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  a     b     c     combined
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#1 a     <NA>  c     a       
#2 <NA>  b     c     b       
#3 a     <NA>  c     a       
#4 <NA>  <NA>  c     c       
#5 a     <NA>  <NA>  a
```

---

Or another option is `do.call`

```
tb %>%
   mutate(combined = select(., uCols) %>% 
                          do.call(coalesce, .))
```